# I am trying to create trigger to calculate sum of products but it is showing me compilation error

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers

```
create or replace trigger total_amt
  2  after insert or delete or update
  3  on products
  4  for each row
  5  BEGIN
  6  update products
  7  SET products.total_prod_amt=(SELECT SUM(products.prod_price) FROM products
  8  WHERE products.prod_id=products.prod_id
  9  END;
 10  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

i am trying this code is it correct. i have to calculate sum of price of all products in my table.

Comment: There is a closing parenthesis missing. But the trigger will fail anyway, because you cannot modify a table in a trigger that is in the progress of changing. And you are not even referring to the altered row. `products.prod_id=products.prod_id` is always true of course, because you compare the value with itself. Then, a product ID should be unique in a product table, so you'd sum the values of a single row? This doesn't seem to make sense. And it is usually a very bad idea to store values redundantly.

Comment: BTW: Your tool doesn't seem to tell you *which* error occured. In that case you can select the error message(s) via `select * from user_errors where name = 'TOTAL_AMT';`.

Comment: Also can you please post the sample data and expected result.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai -while we usually want to see a full, reproducible example, it is not necessary to see test data to solve a compile/syntax issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've added `);` to end the sub-query and the SQL query. The trigger now compiles correctly.
Oracle is now giving different errors because the trigger is trying to modify a table which is mutating.

> ```
> create table products(
> prod_id int primary key,
> prod_price int not null,
> total_prod_amt int  );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create or replace trigger total_amt
>     after insert or delete or update
>     on products
>     for each row
>     BEGIN
>     update products
>     SET products.total_prod_amt= 
>         (SELECT SUM(products.prod_price) 
>          FROM products
>          WHERE products.prod_id=products.prod_id
>         );
>     END;
>    /
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from user_errors;
> ```
>
> ```
> NAME | TYPE | SEQUENCE | LINE | POSITION | TEXT | ATTRIBUTE | MESSAGE_NUMBER
> :--- | :--- | -------: | ---: | -------: | :--- | :-------- | -------------:
> ```

> ```
> insert into products(prod_id, prod_price) values (1,10);
> ```
>
> ```
> ORA-04091: table FIDDLE_DRLOPQIBFWCYUAPCXKVV.PRODUCTS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
> ```

ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_DRLOPQIBFWCYUAPCXKVV.TOTAL_AMT", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_DRLOPQIBFWCYUAPCXKVV.TOTAL_AMT'

> 

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=88ee26f87f35ad14e912db6cb6c30ee6)*